# Cannot display data from openweatherAPI

Tags: reactjs, openweathermap

I'm trying to display some data from OpenWeather API. I can console.log the data and see the object, but from there I do not know how to catch the right value. I will paste some code below.

My problem is that no matter how I try to get some data out of that Object, I seem not to succeed.

`console.log(data)` gives me an object, but every time I try for example `data.main.temp` or `data.city` it gives me an error.

Any suggestions?

```
  state = {
        temperature: null,
        city: undefined,
        country: undefined,
        humidity: undefined,
        description: undefined,
        error: undefined
    }
    getWeather = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
        const country = e.target.elements.country.value;
        const api_call = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`);
        const data = api_call.json();

        console.log(data);        

        //To check after data
        if(city && country){
            this.setState({
                //temperature: data.main.temp,
                //city: data.name,
                //country: data.sys.country,
                //humidity: data.sys.humidity,
                //description: data.weather[0].description,
                error: ""
            });        
        } else {
            this.setState({
                temperature: undefined,
                city: undefined,
                country: undefined,
                humidity: undefined,
                description: undefined,
                error: "Please enter values"
            });

How the object looks while fetched.

Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Object
base: "stations"
clouds: {all: 40}
cod: 200
coord: {lon: -2.24, lat: 53.48}
dt: 1569681998
id: 2643123
main: {temp: 15.43, pressure: 1005, humidity: 87, temp_min: 12.78, temp_max: 17.78}
name: "Manchester"
```

Comment: Could you also tell us what kind of error do you get when trying to access the desired data?

Comment: Yes sorry, here it comes: ×
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `api_call.json()` returns a promise and that's why you're having problems.

I suggest you to try to `await` on that statement aswell:

`const data = await api_call.json();`

More on `fetch` api you can find here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 1):

Have you try use `try/catch` like:

```
getWeather = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let response = null;
    const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
    const country = e.target.elements.country.value;
    try {
        response = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`);
        const data = response.json()
        data && this.setState({
                temperature: data.main && data.main.temp,
                city: data.name,
                country: data.sys && data.sys.country,
                humidity: data.sys && data.sys.humidity,
                description: data.weather[0].description,
                error: ""
            }); 
    } catch (error) {
         this.setState({
                temperature: undefined,
                city: undefined,
                country: undefined,
                humidity: undefined,
                description: undefined,
                error: "Please enter values"
         });
    }
}
```